# How do I change the URL depending on the number of items in input list

Tags: python, api, url

I'm working with APIs and I need to build a URL to retrieve the information I'm asked. The parameter of the function is a list with the codes of different countries. The basic format of the URL is [https://restcountries.com/v2/alpha?codes={code},{code},{code}](https://restcountries.com/v2/alpha?codes=%7Bcode%7D,%7Bcode%7D,%7Bcode%7D) with each code coming from the parameter list. However, the number of items in the list can vary, so how can I build the url with the appropriate number of codes?

For example:
if the list is ["kor", "usa", "de"] the url should look like https://restcountries.com/v2/alpha?codes=kor,usa,de

Comment: use `",".join(codes)`

Answer (score 1):

```
def createUrl(codes):
    url = " https://restcountries.com/v2/alpha?codes="
    for i, code in enumerate(codes):
        url += code
        if i != len(codes)-1: url += ","
    return url
```

For the input `['foo','bar','baz']`, this code will produce https://restcountries.com/v2/alpha?codes=foo,bar,baz

Comment: better use `url += ",".join(codes)`

Comment: @eyllanesc Nice, that's much more elegant